# Why is "In God We Trust" written on US currency?

Tags: united-states, currency

It is written on US currency "**In God we trust**":

[image]

I know that US constitution is secular. [This link](https://www.au.org/resources/publications/is-america-a-christian-nation) says that the founding fathers didn't even like the idea of religion in the system.

**Why is this motto written on US currency**?

This appears unconstitutional, so why do the courts not rule it so? What politics are in play here?

Comment: have you looked at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In_God_We_Trust

Comment: @Max, YES. The Criticism part is vague.

Comment: I'd contend that the "Why doesn't it violate the Constitution" question is legal rather than political, but it's so obvious that it does violate it that really the question is "despite it obviously being unconstitutional, for what political reasons do courts keep upholding it?"

Comment: @IllusiveBrian - if it was "obviously unconstitutional", the court would have ruled on that ages ago. I guess it's not nearly as obvious as you personally think (maybe because the phrase "separation of church and state" isn't actually in the Constitution)

Comment: FWIW some also hold that there's an [illuminati symbol](https://www.illuminatirex.com/illuminati-symbol-great-seal-one-dollar-bill/) on it.

Comment: It is absolutely not clear that the motto is "obviously unconstitutional". The prevailing view in court has been that this _is a legal matter_ rather than a political one, and that the motto is not unconstitutional. See for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aronow_v._United_States

Comment: Briefly (the actual court cases go into much more detail), the reason it is not obviously unconstitutional has to do with the fact that the statement "In God We Trust" does not not elevate one religion over another religion in any clear way. Indeed the concept of a "God" needn't be religious at all. The God could be deistic, or even metaphorical. One can believe in some sort of higher power without being a member of an established religious denomination.

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122, how about someone who is an atheist and also a US citizen?

Comment: @anonymous Atheism is not a religion. It's an epistemological position.

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122, yet, you should accommodate in your constitution.

Comment: I thought the American God was the Dollar itself.. no?

Comment: @anonymous : separation of church and state means that the state is not allowed to force a religion upon you against your will. It does not mean that all cultural references which have a root in religion must be banned. This motto is part of general culture. Saying "how about someone who is an atheist and also a US citizen", is similar to saying "how about someone who doesn't like the color blue and is also a US citizen" and arguing to remove blue from the US flag.

Comment: *why do the courts not rule it so?* Remember that these same courts make you *swear on the bible* to tell the truth.

Comment: @blip *Possible duplicate of <insert completely different question here>*

Comment: "This appears unconstitutional" Why that? Does the constitution say you cannot mention God anywhere?

Comment: To answer "why is has been written". Probably because someone or a group of people liked it that way?

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 It seems to me that it does elevate monotheistic religions over politheistic religions such as Hinduism, Buddhism and Shintoism. Hard to say how that statement is not exclusive or polythetists, or even worse, of atheists.

Comment: @famargar Fair enough, I guess you could make a case for that. Nevertheless, when I think of something that _unequivocally_ violates the first amendment, it would be something like having the verse John 3:16 on the dollar bill. This, on the other hand, is something which requires a certain amount of nontrivial legal interpretation.

Comment: I prefer to think it's just "In Gold we Trust" misspelled ,)

Comment: @vsz, you made a valid point. You should post an answer.

Comment: @vsz - Ummm, placing it as a "national motto" upon money - a required element to function in society - could reasonably be argued to "force a religion upon you against you will" if you don't believe in any God. There is no Constitutional establishment clause barring the use of colors as part of national symbols, so the analogy is not apt.

Comment: @Trilarion - The Consitution says that "Congress shall make no law respecting an establishment of religion" - an official pronouncement of trust in God would seem to be just such an establishment.

Comment: @PoloHoleSet Maybe, maybe not. Is trust in God already a religion by itself. If yes, which religion is it? Godism? Theism?

Comment: @PoloHoleSet : "reasonably argued"? do you reasonably feel forced to go to a church and pray just because of that phrase on the money, and do you think no one will accept the money from you unless you prove you are a member of a specific church? If not, they why would a specific religion be forced upon you?

Comment: @Trilarion - while many different religions could all feel that it might apply to them, the language bars "establishment of religion," not "establishment of ***a*** religion," or "establishment of ***one specific*** religion."  Any and all.

Comment: @vsz - whether I feel forced to go or pray or not is irrelevant. The government may not engage in any activity respecting establishment of religion. The threshold for "establishment" is met well before requiring mandatory compliance from all citizens.

Comment: @PoloHoleSet : then look up what the establishment of something means. What you are arguing for is the prohibition of a motto which is part of general culture. If you tried to ban every single word or phrase in the English language which has some connection to religion, there would be too few words left. Using some words somewhere which make up a well-used phrase which is part of general culture, is not the same as establishing a state religion. Look up what state religion means before claiming that some general words or phrases establish one by themselves.

Comment: @vsz - please.  "In God We Trust" is a generic term without religious meaning?  Gotta call BS on that.  It has a pretty specific meaning.  With the exception of when religious types trot out that phony argument try to push stuff onto everyone, they would take great umbrage at reference to trust in God as generic, general and secular.  This isn't pulling stuff out of context. It's taking the phrase, as a whole, in its original and intended context, not something akin to claiming that the word "the" should be banned because it pops up in the Bible.

Comment: @PoloHoleSet your goal is to get this whole comment section removed, isn't it? Please stop assuming claims I didn't make. I never claimed it has nothing to do with religion. Please read my last post again. My point was that lots of words and phrases with a religious origin are part of (Western) general culture and part of the English language. This is how our culture got shaped for centuries. And the mere existence of these phrases don't legally bind anyone into having to be member of any established religion. Because that's what you were claiming, that the mere existence of them "forces you".

Comment: @PoloHoleSet " "In God We Trust" is a generic term without religious meaning?" Maybe it was in the past, but now... it can only be interpreted as somewhat religious. Why would anyone want to trust in God, if he did not believe in him/her and expect some kind of mystic/religious effect from it? I never said that I trust in God in my whole life. Why would I want to say this on my money bills then? Although I agree that nowadays it's kind of artistic decoration but with a somewhat religious conotation.

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 a lawyer can argue about anything. As a mathematician, you probably know God is singular. And 1 is not equal to many, neither is equal to zero.

Comment: "in God we trust" is not against the constitution because there is more than one monotheistic religion on the planet. So indeed it's not against the constitution, it's just a pretty exclusive message from the government.

Comment: @famargar What do you mean by "pretty exclusive message from the government"? What did they actually mean by it? Why would anyone trust in God if not for religious reasons?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Many people in the US have strong religious views.

This leads to many legislators expressing religious views and supporting legislation with religious implications. Generally calling ourselves a "Christian Nation" has gone out of style, but many religion inspired ideas are supported as not "really" being religious or on nominally non-religious grounds.

People who support a stricter secularism often challenge these rules using the 1st amendment of the constitution's ban on establishing a religion.

So far the courts seem to have ruled that using the word 'God' is not enough to count as establishing a religion as long as some ambiguity is allowed over whose god is meant.

Comment: It's worth noting that it was added to paper currency only in 1957 - and the argument can be made it was added in response to the rise and spread of communism.

Comment: @BruceWayne I think that is perhaps more relevant to the other answer which deals with specific reasons for this instance. My answer is general and aimed at the idea the questioner had.

Comment: Note: "In God we trust": [first added to US coins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-cent_piece_(United_States)#Design) in 1864 during the US civil war - a very difficult time,

Comment: Quite a few Christians will use the phrase "Christian Nation" in reference to the United States.  That doesn't make it legally accurate, but it is a phrase you will hear from time to time.

Comment: Good broad answer, but there's actually a very specific answer: https://www.treasury.gov/about/education/Pages/in-god-we-trust.aspx

Comment: "So far the courts seem to have ruled..." It would be nice to give some citations for such rulings.

Comment: @blip Thanks for posting that link. You could convert that into an answer, summarizing the content of the link and referring to it. That would probably fully answer the question.

Answer (score 10):

"In God We Trust" is the official motto of the United States since 1956, and was one of the nation's unofficial mottos since the 1800s, possibly originating with a line in the fourth stanza of the national anthem: "And this be our motto: 'In God is our Trust'".

Comment: Then, the anthem also seems to be unconstitutional.

Comment: @anonymous I don't think the Constitution says what you think it does.  The separation of church and state comes from a letter Thomas Jefferson wrote, it's not in the Constitution and isn't law.

Comment: @anonymous Your error is "assuming the thing you wish to prove".  Did you come here to ask a question?

Comment: Just to expand on what @JonK said, the First Amendment prohibits "mak[ing] law respecting an establishment of religion, or prohibiting the free exercise thereof". Unless you can show that making this phrase is establishing a religion, or preventing you from exercising yours, it is *not* unconstitutional.  People have tried to show that it's "establishing religion", but per the Wikipedia page, no one has succeeded in court yet.

Comment: @Bobson Not only that but it means "law" literally, that was a compromise between the states and is pretty well documented from when it was written, and the anthem is not a law.

Comment: @JonK Wouldn't it be a law that establishes a certain song as the anthem, though?

Comment: @Bobson Not necessarily, no: it could just be a matter of tradition.

Comment: @DavidRicherby it could just be tradition, but it isn't.  It's a statute ([36 USC 301](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/36/301)). It was enacted on March 4, 1931.

Comment: This is true, but not why it was added to money.

Comment: @Bobson "...but per the Wikipedia page, no one has succeeded in court yet." At least it made it to court. That probably means it's controversial.

Answer (score 9):

You raise several questions.

In semi reverse order of your asking them:

1. Is displaying "In God We Trust" on US currency unconstitutional?

No. Not according to the US Courts system, which the U.S. uses for constitutional interpretation. See, for example, Aronow v. United States, where the ruling included:

> It is quite obvious that the national motto and the slogan on coinage
>   and currency 'In God We Trust' has nothing whatsoever to do with the
>   establishment of religion. Its use is of patriotic or ceremonial
>   character and bears no true resemblance to a governmental sponsorship
>   of a religious exercise. ...It is not easy to discern any religious
>   significance attendant the payment of a bill with coin or currency on
>   which has been imprinted 'In God We Trust' or the study of a
>   government publication or document bearing that slogan.

2. Why do the courts not rule it unconstitutional

Because it does not *establish a state religion*, which is what the first amendment bars Congress from doing.

3. Why is this motto written on US currency?

The motto started out on coins.

The motto first appeared on the 1864 two-cent coin following collaboration between the Mint Director, the Secretary of the Treasury and Congress to place the motto on that coin. Further legislation from Congress in the 1860s and 1870s allowed the motto to be used on additional coins. And since 1938, it has appeared on all US coins.

Later, in 1955 Congress passed a law that "'In God We Trust' ... shall appear on all United States currency and coins".

So, the reason the motto is written on US currency is that Congress passed a law saying it would be.

4. What politics are in play here?

The [U.S. Department of the Treasury speculates](https://www.treasury.gov/about/education/Pages/in-god-we-trust.aspx) the motto made its way onto coins in the 1860s because:

> The motto IN GOD WE TRUST was placed on United States coins largely
>   because of the increased religious sentiment existing during the Civil
>   War. Secretary of the Treasury Salmon P. Chase received many appeals
>   from devout persons throughout the country, urging that the United
>   States recognize the Deity on United States coins.

The move to add it to paper currency in the 1950s coincides with Congress establishing "In God We Trust" as the national motto, establishing an annual National Day of Prayer, and adoption of the Pledge of Allegiance which includes the phrase "One nation, under God". All of this happened at a time when the U.S. was facing off against the atheistic communism of the Soviet Union, which I suspect was the driving popular/political force -- to differentiate the United States as having a capitalistic and deistic ideology.

5. Did the founding fathers dislike the idea of religion "in the system"

The Constitution only mentions religion in the first amendment, which bars Congress from establishing a State religion. In that regard, the Constitution is a secular document - it certainly does not establish some sort of theocracy.

At the same time though, other founding documents like the Declaration of Independence make explicit appeals to a Creator.

Furthermore, while the amended Constitution forbade establishing a Federal State Church, many individual U.S. States had State Churches during and after the founding period. Connecticut's remained until 1818.

Trying to pin down a consensus of the founders on the appropriate interplay of religion and government is messy. I think an anecdote that captures this well is that the first two US presidents, George Washington and John Adams, both proclaimed national days of prayer as President. But then our third President, Thomas Jefferson refused to do the same, replying to Rev. Samuel Miller as follows:

> I consider the government of the United States as interdicted by the
>   Constitution from inter meddling with religious institutions, their
>   doctrines, discipline, or exercises

James Madison, the fourth president, resumes the practice. Then it basically ends until the 1950s (right around when Congress decrees "In God We Trust" should go on paper currency).

Similarly, Washington proclaimed an explicitly religious day of Thanksgiving. Then Thanksgiving fell out of practice from 1815 until the Civil War period in the 1860s, where Lincoln puts out a Thanksgiving proclamation that goes so far in regard to religious content that it includes:

> They are the gracious gifts of the Most High God, who, while dealing
>   with us in anger for our sins, hath nevertheless remembered mercy

(And at that same time, "In God We Trust" starts going on coins.)

Answer (score 1):

There is *quite a lot* of history there. Essentially, it reduces to a claim that natural rights exist, and that they are cannot be abrogated by kings. See Locke's first treatise for a great example of that reasoning.

If you look back at the revolution, you'll see similar language all over the place. For example, one of the original revolutionary flags (the liberty tree) has "An appeal to heaven" along the top.

Googling around, I found this discussion of [New England ministers](http://www.libertyparkusafd.org/CD-ROMs/America's%20Divine%20Origin%20and%20Destiny%20-%2021%20-%20The%20New%20England%20Clergy%20and%20the%20American%20Revolution.html); the philosophy described in chapter 2 is a reasonable starting point for why this was a very important point.

Comment: Could you explain how the existence of these "natural rights" and the absence of kings in the USA leads specifically to "In God we trust" being written on the money? In particular, it wasn't there until the 1950s so, while the use of similar language during the revolution is clearly relevant, it can't be the _reason_.

Comment: @DavidRicherby The Treasury disagrees with you. https://www.treasury.gov/about/education/Pages/in-god-we-trust.aspx

Comment: OK, fine, since 1864. That was still a long time after the revolution so my actual point still stands.

Comment: @DavidRicherby the founding principles of America had and continue to have profound effects on the national character. If you want to read about it, Locke is public domain, and de Tocqueville is as well.